# Annotations in PHPStorm by Symfony2 plugin

Tags: symfony, configuration, annotations, phpstorm

I try to set Symfony2 plugin so I can use annotations. I installed the [plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm), PHPStorm restarted and the cache was invalidated.

And now, some code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

When I put `@ORM\` and I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> I see `No suggesions`.

This doesn’t work? I set something wrong?

Comment: have you imported `Mapping` by `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` ?

Comment: yes, I have imported.

Comment: already works fine, `PHPStorm 8.x` and plugins `Symfony2 Plugin` and `PHP Annotations`.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the wrong plugin :)
[PHP Annotations](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7320)

[image: phpstorm php annotation]

Answer (score 3):

For future visitors, just click **File->Invalidate caches/Restart...** and everything will work.
https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-annotation-plugin#install

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm doesn't support doctrine annotation for the moment.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6187

But maybe there's more informations about this somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a full code completion for annotations of Symfony framework and others, you should install first the Symfony Plugin then PHP annotations, [this article shows what you should install in PHPStorm to code faster Symfony Applications](http://refreshmymind.com/symfony-plugins-phpstorm/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, whenever i installed php annotation plugin from github it was not working.

Issue was resolved once i installed plugin from latest .jar file from history section of plugin home page.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7320

[image]